# Parameter count Exception: GetValue of System.String

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reflection

I´m working on a class which generates a property tree, but I have a problem with some arrays and primitive data types which contain arrays.

In example string has properties Chars and Length
How can I access Chars by using GetValue without using Length?
The main point why I don´t want to use the Length property is, because I don´t know if there is any class which contains a Length property or not

```
public class Util
{
    public static IDictionary<String,Object> PrintProperties(Type type, Object obj)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        IDictionary<String, Object> propertyDict = new Dictionary<String,Object>();


        if (properties.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Name);

               if (properties[i].PropertyType.GetProperties().Length > 1)
                {
                    Object value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i].Name).GetValue(obj, null);
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        propertyDict[properties[i].Name] = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyDict[properties[i].Name] = Util.PrintProperties(properties[i].PropertyType, obj.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i].Name).GetValue(obj, null));
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // MY PROBLEM
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + properties[i].GetValue(obj, null));
                        propertyDict[properties[i].Name] = properties[i].GetValue(obj, null);

                    }
                    catch (TargetParameterCountException e)
                    { 
                        // Array



                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }



            }
        }

        return propertyDict;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your certain that GetValue will be a sure in the list? Then legth should be there as well.

Comment: I think I´m sure. And in any case there would be always a length property?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample class which provides the getchars and not length. Moreover everything's base class is object so you will always get these length